# Python simplepyged graphical representation of family trees

Tags: python, graph-layout, family-tree, gedcom

Does anyone know a way to use the python package simplepyged (for parsing gedcom files) for graphical representation of family trees? XY-Pic? Matlibplot? pictex?

I appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Author here. Sorry, [simplepyged](https://github.com/dijxtra/simplepyged) does not support anything like that. But, if you wish, we can code it together :-)